# Can't install npm packages anymore due to macOS Big Sur upgrade

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install, macos-big-sur

After upgrade to macOS Big Sur I can't do `npm install` with npm older then 7 (so npm v7 is fine).
Anytime I'm getting the error message **Maximum call stack size exceeded** upon clean project folder (without the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file).

I'm tied to use

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.0.1
BuildVersion:   20B50
Darwin: 20.1.0
nodejs v14.15.1
npm version 6.14.8
```

I tried:

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm rebuild`

Install Node manually, by Homebrew, by nvm and also downgrade npm to various lower versions.

Reinstall Homebrew to get fresh background as it was used before upgrade to Big Sur.

Reinstall xcode command-line tools.

Run the node and map the project in the docker container ubuntu:focal.

Couple last lines of the output return by `npm install --loglevel verbose`:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dashdash/-/dashdash-1.14.1.tgz 23ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl/-/tweetnacl-0.14.5.tgz 15ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl/-/tweetnacl-0.14.5.tgz 14ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Completed in 51352ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree Completed in 51653ms
npm timing stage:generateActionsToTake Completed in 225ms
npm verb correctMkdir /Users/dominikjelinek/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using /Users/dominikjelinek/.npm/_locks/staging-a03ae73070af7d1f.lock for /Users/dominikjelinek/home/ccb-survey/survey/components/node_modules/.staging
npm timing audit submit Completed in 931ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick 931ms
npm timing audit body Completed in 3ms
npm timing action:extract Completed in 7997ms
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 91317ms
npm verb unlock done using /Users/dominikjelinek/.npm/_locks/staging-a03ae73070af7d1f.lock for /Users/dominikjelinek/home/ccb-survey/survey/components/node_modules/.staging
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 156352ms
npm WARN react-plotly.js@2.5.1 requires a peer of plotly.js@>1.34.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm verb stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm verb stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
npm verb stack     at isDepOptional (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:432:45)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:441:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb stack     at failedDependency (/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
npm verb cwd /Users/dominikjelinek/home/ccb-survey/survey/components
npm verb Darwin 20.1.0
npm verb argv "/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/node" "/Users/dominikjelinek/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin/npm" "install" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb node v14.15.1
npm verb npm  v6.14.8
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

**UPDATE 1**

Apple released new system upgrade, what didn't help.
ProductVersion: 11.1

I don't think that it is the permissions issue as I set the project to 777 for all `chmod -R 777 project`.

As far as I know my mates are running npm v6 on Big Sur fine.

In the docker container, I copied the project from the mapped folder to some other folder in the docker container and `npm install` is working as expected.

Same is happening for Windows 10 running in the VirtualBox, where npm is not working upon shared folder, but works after copy the project to some inner folder in the VirtualBox Windows machine.

Raised an issue in the [npm cli issue tracking](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2363).

Raised an issue in the [docker issue tracking](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4859).

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to create new user on my mac machine to start partially fresh, I installed nvm as described [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and ran `nvm install v14.15.4` with npm v6.14.10.

Still same problem.

Comment: We face the same issues in my company. After cornering the issue down to be related somehow to the filesystem we found this post of yours! Especially the issue with docker working inside the container but not on a mounted file volume from the Mac host. Colleges with older macs have no issues but 3 do have issues (all freshly installed macs) 

We have a workaroung though! npm 7 seems to work just fine. Also yarn seems to work most times.

Comment: I did actually check if our Anti Virus affects this (Was just a feeling) and it was unfortunately true. After disabling it all worked absolutely fine -.-. All the symptoms were the exact same as you described it. Any chance you're also running Trend Micro Security Agent?

Comment: Thank you for this information. It is really interesting one. We decide to upgrade to npm v7 in team to solve this only my problem. But I'm wondering if anybody from your team is getting some Interrupted system call in relation to git operation as well as this is another issue appearing on my system without any obvious pattern, so I can't work with repository, `git fsck` return plenty errors and `git gc --aggressive --prune=now --force` doesn't help. This also start after the Big Sure upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, thank you @Flowkap, all issues:

1. mentioned `npm install`
2. double machine reboot after sleep of more then 24 hours
3. error when using SentryWebpackPlugin during the build process
4. [local git repository corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623912/broken-git-repository-after-chmod-operation?noredirect=1#comment116049107_65623912) issue I raised as well

**All solved by removing the Trend Micro Security**

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue. It was solved by increasing the file's `ulimit`.

To check what you have right now, do:

> ulimit -a

That should display something like this:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              12288
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       2784
-n: file descriptors                12288
```

Then, to increase the file size limit, run the following:

> ulimit -f [WHATEVER SIZE LIMIT YOU WANT]

For myself, I decided to set it to `unlimited` to make sure this would not be a problem again, so:

> ulimit -f unlimited

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately this is not my case. My file size is set to unlimited already, so I was brave enough to change the files descriptors from 256 to unlimited, but it didn't help.

Comment: Hum... That's unfortunate. Just as a test, could you change them all to unlimited?  Just curious at this point.

Comment: Also, make sure to do this on the same Terminal tab where you are running your `npm install`. (I know this may seem dumb, but I had not realized it myself until having to do this multiple times

Comment: Still same problem. I reboot the machine to be sure also. But I couldn't set to unlimited all options ... the stack size has literal limit as well as the processes.

Comment: Crap... That's annoying. Will keep an eye out for a better solution and will update my post accordingly if anything comes my way.