# Broken git repository after chmod operation

Tags: git

After I did `chmod -R 755 /.../[repo_root]/some_inner_project_folder` upon more then 5000 files, `git add .` and `git commit -m "..."` and `git push` I've got **Interrupted system call** errors.

I solved my problem by re-clone the repository and copy over whatever is differ between new and old local repository.

But I'm continuously getting this issue with git and not sure how to avoid it.
So after error, I'm getting something like this from the `git fsck`:

```
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/03/503a48d98793cd58fbdf18e6f2aafa19616a15: Interrupted system call
error: 03503a48d98793cd58fbdf18e6f2aafa19616a15: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/03/503a48d98793cd58fbdf18e6f2aafa19616a15
```

Sometimes, I'm successful with `git gc --aggressive --prune=now --force` and sometimes not.

It happened on the repository used by multiple devs and upon the one used by me only.

**Update 1**

The files I was working with belong to inner folder of the git repository.
I didn't touch the `.git` folder.

Comment: Does the error appear for the owner of the files in the git directory or for other users on the system?

Comment: no, only my problem unfortunately

Comment: I don't mean if the problem occurs for multiple users of the shared git repository. I meant if it occurs just for the owner of the local linux directory (where you store the repository) or other users of this directory.

Comment: I see, there is no other user I can use at the moment. The repository is placed in my home folder.

Comment: Why did you set the permissions to `755`, then?

Comment: Because the project is web application and the Apache server couldn't read the files.

Comment: You could try to not run the `chmod` command in the `.git` directory but only on the files required for the apache server. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314952/378034) might help you.

Comment: I was changing the files in the inner project folder actually. I didn't mention for simplicity. But I didn't change anything in the .git folder and when I clone the project again and changed the file permissions again and push, all was fine. What can cause it?

Comment: The problem is that you modified the contents of the `.git` directory and git may require some things, there.

Comment: That's not correct, as I wrote above, I didn't change anything in the .git directory. That issue start happening after my system upgrade, but can't find what is wrong as I can't find any specific command causing it.

Comment: If you change the parent directory recursively, it will also change the `.git` directory

Comment: I meant that it obvious ... so I mentioned: I tweak the permissions of files from the inner project folder. The project is the git repository, so I changed files from the inner folder of the  project/git repository. This start to be a bit unproductive, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @domino : could you edit the beginning of your question to highlight what you did starting from the root of your repo ? e.g : `cd innerDir/; chmod -R 755 .` (if I understood correctly) ?

Comment: Sure thing ....

Comment: "interrupted system call" errors are not a *Git* issue. Your system is installed improperly somehow. It's not possible to say how from what you've shown here, but this has nothing to do with Git. Are you using FUSE (user space file systems) and/or NFS?

Comment: No, I'm not using FUSE/NFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to the **Trend Micro Security** as [discovered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286917/cant-install-npm-packages-anymore-due-to-macos-big-sur-upgrade/65768447#65768447).

I was getting multiple "interrupted system call" and I couldn't do `git push` anymore. So I marked these git repos as non fixable.

The issue appeared after `chmod` command I mentioned on top in the particular project, but when I uninstall the Trend Micro Security I was able to fix project by `git gc` as mentioned as well.